# How to lock LandScapte mode when i click hardware back button in react-native-video player?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

```
I am using Orientation library for Portrait and Landscape mode,
```

i have made a function for managing Full Screen mode and change state accordingly and pass state to full screen props of react-native-video player, but when i click back button still my app is in Landscape mode but i want app should be show in Portrait mode after click back button, how can i achieve it, please if anyone have any suggestion please help.

here i am sharing code...

```
  import Video from 'react-native-video';
  import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation';
  FullScreenVisible = () => {
    const { fullscreen } = this.state;
    if (fullscreen) {
        Orientation.lockToPortrait();
    } else {
        Orientation.lockToLandscape();
    }
    this.setState({ fullscreen: !fullscreen });
}
                                   <Video
                                
                                    fullscreen={fullscreen}
                                    paused={paused} 
                                    ref={ref => this.video = ref}
                                    source={{ uri: this.state.video }}
                                    style={{
                                        position: 'absolute',
                                        top: 0,
                                        left: 0,
                                        bottom: 0,
                                        right: 0
                                    }}
                                    resizeMode='contain'
                                    onLoad={({duration})=>this.setState({duration})}
                                    
                                    onProgress={({currentTime})=>this.setState({currentTime})}
                                // onVideoEnd={this.onEndVideo}
                                />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    I had posted this question few day's ago.
```

I got the solution that day after spending some hours' but i forgot post the answer, now i am post the answer of my question.
May be it will help someone.
Thank you.

we will add BackHandler.
addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackAction) in componentDidMount.

const handleBackAction = ()=>{
Orientation.lockToPortrait();}